# Definition of Entropy (Information Theory)

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, information-theory, entropy, data-mining

In Information Theory, entropy is defined as:

$$-\sum_{i}P_ilog(P_i)$$

where $-P_ilog(P_i)$ looks like this (using log base 2):

[image]

From just a generic English definition of entropy, meaning lack of predictability, I don't find this particularly intuitive.  Would you not have the most entropy (be the most uncertain) when $P_i=0.5$?  In other words, would it not make more sense to use a measure like this:

$$-\sum_{i}4P_i(P_i-1)$$

where $-4P_i(P_i-1)$ looks like this:

[image]

instead?  What is the advantage of using $P_ilog(P_i)$?

Comment: Please disregard my now-deleted comments. Your definition of entropy corresponds to what is known as [Tsallis entropy with entropy-index 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsallis_entropy). This is a generalization of Shannon entropy, and in fact, Shannon entropy is exactly Tsallis entropy with entropy-index 1. In particular, they share many properties. But Shannon entropy $H$ enjoys an additional property called *additivity*, which says that $H(X,Y)=H(X)+H(Y)$ for independent $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: The sum that you are ignoring is also important.  That is, if you are flipping a fair coin (i.e. your $P_i=0.5$), it's also important that you sum over the two states (heads and tails).  In _both_ formulas you give, you'll find the maximum entropy of $P_1 = p, P_2 = 1-p$ will occur when $p=0.5$

Comment: Your first graph is wrong, what you should have plotted was $\text{H}(x)=-x\log(x) - (1-x)\log(1-x)$, which does in fact have its maxima at $x=0.5$.

Comment: @Thoth, his first graph is a plot of an individual additive term in the overall entropy ... and I believe it was indicated as such